# AJAX returning data from a PHP page with code inside

Tags: php, ajax

I got the following ajax where I want to send data from a < form > to a PHP page, where the data will be stored in a DataBase and then I will return a password generated in the PHP to the AJAX, but seems that I can't succeed

```
$.ajax({
   type:'POST',
   url:'register.php',
   data:$('#form_register').serialize(),
});
```

I'm new to AJAX and every answer I saw was just a PHP page with a few lines of code, it's impossible to use the JSON response in a PHP page with more code?

Comment: What do you have in `register.php`? Can you dump the `$_POST`?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? You don't seem to have any code to handle the response from the server, and you aren't showing your PHP code.

Comment: please showing your php code do something

Comment: Is you want to handle the response returned from register.php add the function to your ajax (see http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). In the callback given to this function you can handle the response.

Comment: In the PHP i just got code to connect to DB and execute the query to save it. I should add in the bottom of the page a json_encode or just do the json_enconde in another page?

Comment: Can we see the source code of your `register.php` file? And possibly, the relevant parts of your form code, also. It would help.

Comment: If you want to return something from the code you call via AJAX, the simplest way is to echo it in the script called via AJAX. So do an "echo json_encode(...)" at the bottom of register.php.
As mentioned above, you can handle this response in the jQuery done function concated to $.ajax()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to return some data from your register.php, you have to output it in this file:

```
<?php
// register.php

/* Do whatever has to be done here */

echo json_encode(<your data-array here>); // Encode the data you want to return here
```

In your script where the ajax request is made you have to handle the response from register.php

```
$.ajax({
   type:'POST',
   url:'register.php',
   data:$('#form_register').serialize()
}).done(function(returnedData) {
   // Process the returnedData
});
```

Comment: The solution was this, my main problem was json_encode was broking the page at some point but now is fine. Thanks!